# Selecting rows where the value of 2 columns occur in some list of tuples

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause

This question is best asked with an example.

Consider a table like:

```
Main | P1 | P2
==============
1    | 1  | 1
2    | 1  | 3
3    | 1  | 1
4    | 2  | 3
...
```

I want to issue a query that returns all `Main` values where the values of `P1` and `P2` occur in a list of tuples.

For instance, if I had the list `[(1,1), (2,3)]` I would want rows where:

- `P1` is `1` and `P2` is `1`  OR where
- `P1` is `2` and `P2` is `3`.

For the table above that would be the rows where `Main` is `1`, `3` or `4`.

I think I can achieve this with something like:

```sql
SELECT Main 
WHERE CONCAT(P1, P2) IN ("11", "13")
```

But I suspect this won't use any of the indexes I have on `P1` or `P2`. Assuming I have a lot of data is there a nicer way to issue this query that will make use of the indexes?

**EDIT**

I've subsequently found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9140015/how-to-get-rows-which-match-a-list-of-3-tuples-conditions-with-sqlalchemy) which answers my question too (I was using sqlalchemy)

Answer (score 4):

I think you just want `in` with tuples:

```
where (p1, p2) in ( (1, 1), (2, 3) )
```

Comment: Oh, I'd just assumed it would be more complicated than that. I'll give that a go. Thanks